# This site has accessibility problems

Tags: discussion

In my opinion, too many questions and too many answers rely on images and videos. To be [accessible to the visually impaired](http://www.afb.org/info/programs-and-services/technology-evaluation/creating-accessible-websites/123), authors who use images in their questions and answers should write something along the lines of

![One thousand word exposé on what the linked image portrays](http:/link/to/image)

Rant over.

Comment: Note to self: Fix the accessibility problem with [this answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/121830/does-earth-really-have-two-high-tide-bulges-on-opposite-sides/121858#121858) and [this answer](http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/88/how-is-the-mass-of-the-earth-determined/523#523), and most likely, with other answers written by me.

Comment: This is a good point. Image markup does have the ability to insert alt text for images, but I find in a lot of cases that the alt text is not very helpful. This is perhaps an area that we could improve on as a community.

Comment: Videos should be supplementary only. Neither question or answer should rely on video--the information needed for the post should be written in the post.

Comment: @called2voyage I think this is really important. While there's *a lot* of activity behind the ["don't use jet"](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/10/16/how-bad-is-your-colormap/) movement for uniform color maps more friendly to the ~1% who have some kind of color blindness (there is haiku as well, if you look for it), I think many including myself just default to "oh well..." when thinking about the visually impaired reading our stuff. If the SE ecosystem had a resource for this even half as good as the one for [mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/284619) that would be great!

Comment: @called2voyage while there is not much more that can be done for [questions like this](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/13595/12102) as far as moving information to text, *I was able* to put everything into text in [this question](http://meta.space.stackexchange.com/q/756/12102). Of course in the second case, the image is of text anyway :)

Comment: @DavidHammen this is a good point - the link to the AFB recommendations [Creating Accessible Websites](http://www.afb.org/info/programs-and-services/technology-evaluation/creating-accessible-websites/123) is a good place to start. Those are *great answers* by the way! I've asked a [follow-up question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/257674/83380) already.

Comment: I attacked [my answer on the tidal bulge](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/121830/does-earth-really-have-two-high-tide-bulges-on-opposite-sides/121858#121858), and now I have another question: Why the distinction between the alt-text and the caption? Perhaps that should be a meta feature request.

Comment: @DavidHammen thats probably from HTML - `alt text` is for cases when the image cannot be shown - text browser, file not available, iirc for the screen readers for the visually impaired - and should say what the image represents; `title text` (which I suppose `caption` translates to) is for when you hover over the image and it shows "additional" text which you will see together with the image. But browsers make it a bit hard because for historical reasons some may show one in place of the other when only one of them is defined.